# Rewriting multi-threaded event-driven C++ program to use single-threaded boost::asio

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I am working on refactoring a large code base responsible for IO operations.  Currently the program is comprised of a number of threads, each of which waits for proprietary events to be received.  Events are posted to a global event queue and are received by all threads (a global event dispatcher calls an event handler function for every thread and that thread determines whether or not it should do something based on the event type and, if necessary, adds that event to its own work queue).

This architecture has a lot of overhead, both due to having a lot of threads (around 12 on a single arm core) which are mostly sleeping and due to the work queues.  It also requires a few hundred different event classes which reduces maintainability.

I would like to replace this event based architecture with a single threaded boost asio methodology but am unsure of what paradigm I should use to do this.  I think boost::io_service might be the best but perhaps coroutines, fibers, or something else would be better.

Does anyone have any suggestions what boost::asio paradigm would result in the smoothest transition when moving away from an event queue?  I am looking for something that will improve code maintainability rather than making the code completely incomprehensible in exchange for reduced overhead.

This looks promising, but the coroutine syntax is a bit scary and it is going to be hard to sell to the rest of my team:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/coroutine/doc/html/coroutine/motivation.html

Comment: This looks like a question more suited for [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) than SO to me. The difference in scope from it and SO is a bit of a gray area for me, though, so I'll refrain from voting.

Comment: The co-routines are optional, you don't have to use to take an advantage of `asio::io_service`-based dispatch. Just make the event-handlers "nullary" function objects, and `post()` them to the `io_service` -- and they will be invoked asynchronously.

Comment: @IgorR.  Thanks, that was what I was hoping just not experienced with boost:asio.

Comment: @CássioRenan Thanks, I will check out that stack exchange. I have not heard of it before.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [boost.fiber](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/fiber/doc/html/index.html) - it provides an API like std::thread.
You do not necessarily need boost.asio